# R studio, count, sum & percentage by specific brand

Tags: r, count, sum, percentage

I am struggling with 3 issues in R studio. Even I could calculate the very simple way, it was not very clean(like many times using filter functions). This is a sample dataset in below.
[The dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OmO6.png)
.

Actually, the real dataset contains more than 1 million, so I would like to know an efficient way to calculate it. Also, if it is possible, I want to avoid creating new datasets.

What I want to do in this set is that

1. How to summarise "the count of household by brand A" ?
2. How to summarise "the sum of sales by brand A" ?
3. How to summarise "brand A percentage of all household"(I mean "penetration") ?

Thank you for your help. I really appreciate that.

Comment: that is not a dataset , it is an image ;-)... please use the results from `dput()` when sharing data.. Also; what poart of your code are you stuck on, what error messages/results do you get?? Please share...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect example of where to use the collection of packages called tidyverse (https://www.tidyverse.org). dplyr is package within tidyverse which provides an incredibly simple,  transparent, and readable way to do this. You don't have to create new dataframes.

In your dataset, I believe the column household is an ID number for household. (If it's actually number of households, the code can easily be adjusted to answer your question)

1. Count of households by brand A:

```
countbrandA<-dataset %>% filter(brand=="A") %>% summarize(N=n())
```

2. The sum of sales by brand A

```
totalsalesbrandA <- filter(brand=="A") %>% summarize(salestotal=sum(sales))
```

3. Brand A percentage of all household. First get the total number of households with brand A, then divide by the total.

```
grandtotal<-dataset %>% summarize(N=n())
brandpercentageA=countbrandA/grandtotal
```

Or to get proportion for each brand in a single dplyr pipe, you could do

```
brandpercentage <- dataset %>% 
    group_by(brand) %>% 
    summarize(N=n()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(percent=N/grandtotal)
```

Comment: Should your (2) instead be `totalsalesbrandA <- dataset %>% ...`? I suspect your (3) could benefit from `group_by(brand)` to keep the calculation completely within a `dplyr` pipe.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the error and improved the solution based on your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `data.table`. There are many resources that will tell you how to summarise variables and there are several different ways to do so.

If you read about `data.table` [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/) it will also answer your question.

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(reprex)

x <- data.table(code = 1:5,
                sales = 2000,
                household = c(12345, 3598, 456, 45698, 4875),
                brand = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A"))

# gives counts by brands and then filtered for brand A
one <- x[, .N, by = .(brand)] %>% 
  .[brand == "A"]

# gives sums by brand
two <- x[, sum(sales), by = .(brand)] %>% 
  .[brand == "A"]

# make new column with percent of household
x[, percent := household / sum(x$household)]

# summarise the percent
three <- x[, sum(percent), by = .(brand)]
```

Created on 2019-02-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).